# Pass a radio button selected value and use that to register user with additional parameter

Tags: express, google-authentication

I want to be able to register different users  based on a radio selection using google auth .This is a nodejs ,express ,jade webapp.

**signup.jade looks like this .**

```
.form-group.row.radio-role
            label.col-sm-4 Sign Up as
            label.col-sm-4.radio.radio-inline
              input(type='radio', id='mentee',name='role', value='mentee' required='')
              span Mentee
            label.col-sm-4.radio.radio-inline
              input(type='radio',id='mentor', name='role', value='mentor')
              span Mentor
        laterShow
          a.btn.btn-google(href='/auth/google') Register using Google
          .divider
            hr.left
```

I make the user select whether he wants to be a mentor or mentee and then display the sign up as google link. The issue is I am unable to pass this info that it is for a mentor or mentee to the backend.

**I have tried :**

**01)** I have tried adding parameters to the url and then trying to authenticate but google authentication code isnt working if thats the case

**02)** I have tried to add parameters to session but i am unable to read the session variables in jade as well.

Comment: Could you show the backend code especially the post route handler

Comment: With 'google auth' you mean [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2])?